# Is $\mathbb Z_7$ an extension of $\mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field, monomorphisms

Is $\mathbb Z_7$ a extension of $\mathbb Z_2?$

I know it is not, because we can't establish a monomorphism between  $\mathbb Z_7$ and $\mathbb Z_2$,i.e. it doesn't exist an injective homomorphism between them.

But how can I prove it formally?

Comment: If you know that some property does not hold for a statement and want to prove it, generally contradiction works.

Comment: @FickyLicky so I would start the proof like this: suppose there exist a monomorphism from $Z_2$ to $Z_7$ given by...? given by what relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a map $f : \mathbf{Z}_2 \to \mathbf{Z}_7$. If it is a homomorphism, we must have $f(0) = 0$. That just leaves open the question of what $f(1)$ is. Since it is a homomorphism we want $f(1 + 1) = f(1) + f(1)$. Is there a value of $f(1)$ for which this works?

Comment: That's the simplest answer! But for field extensions, we want $f(1)=1$.

Comment: @lhf no, for homomorphism we want this f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b) and f(ab)=f(a)f(b). and for monomorphism we want f to be injective, so f(1)=1

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* Can a group of order $2$ be a subgroup of a group of order $7$ ?

If $E$ is an extension field of $F$, then the additive group of $F$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $E$.

Comment: yes, I guess yes a group of order 2 can be a subgroup of a group of order 7

Comment: then what do I do?

Comment: @AnneliseToft, do you know Lagrange's theorem of group theory?

Comment: nop, let me google it

Comment: I already read it